# Need help formulating a correct JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am a novice using Jquery ajax calls and json responses and have hit a bump that I need help to overcome.

I am using [cleeng open API](http://cleeng.com/open/v3/Reference) and I am wondering about the response from one of the api calls I am using – [getRentalOffer()](http://cleeng.com/open/v3/Reference/Rental_Offer_API/Functions/getRentalOffer).

I am using jquery $ajax() request and I want to make the getRentalOffer() api call and return the result in JSON format. My efforts so far is this (assume a POST request with id as parameter.)

Request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#getOfferButton" ).click(function() {


            var offerId = document.frm.offerID.value;

            $.ajax({
                // the URL for the request
                url: "ajax-get-offer.php",

                // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
                data: {
                    id: offerId
                },

                // whether this is a POST or GET request
                type: "POST",

                // the type of data we expect back
                dataType : "json",

                // code to run if the request succeeds;
                // the response is passed to the function
                success: function(json) {



                // $("#title").val = json.title;
                  /*
                   $.each(json, function(i, item){
                           $("#"+item.field).val(item.value);
                        }); 
                   */
                 console.log(json);

                },

                // code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
                // status codes are passed to the function
                error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
                    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                    console.log( "Status: " + status );
                    console.dir( xhr );
                },

                // code to run regardless of success or failure
                complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                    alert( "The request is complete!" );
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
```

ajax-get-offer.php:

```
<?php
include_once('Cleeng-cleeng-php-sdk-fe2a543/cleeng_api.php');
/*
Using FirePHP to log variables
*/
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);

$offerID = $_POST['id'];


$firephp->log($offerID, 'offerID');//For debugging

$publisherToken = 'My super secret token goes here!';
$cleengApi = new Cleeng_Api();
$cleengApi->setPublisherToken($publisherToken);
$offerDetails = $cleengApi->getRentalOffer($offerID);


$firephp->log($offerDetails, 'offerDetails');//For debugging

echo $offerDetails;
?>
```

When I try this I get Internal server error. I tried to use echo json_encode($offerDetails); on that last echo statement and then I do not get the server error. However the response only seem to contain the last element of the JSON object.

I need help to understand what I need to do with the API response from getRentalOffer() in order to pass it as a proper JSON response to the $ajax() request.

I hope my question make sense. :-)

Edit: Using print_r insead of echo I do get a response text but sadly with an error. This is the text and it looks to me as if it need to be formatted correctly before using print_r.

```
"Cleeng_Entity_RentalOffer Object ( [id:protected] => R875937249_SE [publisherEmail:protected] => martin.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.se [url:protected] => http://xxx.xxxxxx.xx/cleeng_tool [title:protected] => Tjohooo! [description:protected] => En skön rulle om Afrika. [price:protected] => 55 [applicableTaxRate:protected] => 0.21 [period:protected] => 48 [currency:protected] => EUR [socialCommissionRate:protected] => 0 [contentType:protected] => video [contentExternalId:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxx [contentExternalData:protected] => {"platform":"vimeo","dimWidth":"500","dimHeight":"369","hasPreview":false,"previewVideoId":"","backgroundImage":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/xxxxxxxxx_960.jpg"} [contentAgeRestriction:protected] => [tags:protected] => Array ( [0] => abo ) [active:protected] => 1 [createdAt:protected] => 1400588711 [updatedAt:protected] => 1400606512 [pending:protected] => [averageRating] => 4 ) "
```

Comment: I could really really use some help. :-)

Comment: it the right option to use `echo json_encode($offerDetails)` rather than `echo $offerDetails`

Comment: i want to see your code here: `$cleengApi->getRentalOffer()` i think its just passing one row, and not rows.

Comment: It is indeed passing all rows, I checked $offerDetails with FirePHP to be sure.

Comment: can you paste `json_encoded` results instead of `print_r`? and i really want to see your `getRentalOffer()` function.

Comment: offerDetails_json: {"averageRating":4}

Comment: Not sure I follow you? The getRentalOffer() call is in the original post inside ajax-get-offer.php. If you need more info on that this is the place: http://cleeng.com/open/v3/Reference/Rental_Offer_API/Functions/getRentalOffer

Comment: I think this might be the reason json_encode only returns the last element: "json_encode() will only encode public member variables.". See, averageRating is the only member variable that is public.

Comment: so you need the other elements as well then?

Comment: Yes, I do. I managed to solve it now. Thanks you for your effort Viscocent, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The object returned by getRentalOffer() contains protected members which will not be encoded by json_encode because it respects the access parameters in the object vars. I found a nice solution in this post: http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/34-web/65-json-encoding-private-class-members

It is not a robust solution as it relies on a loophole that one day might be shut so beware of that. But for my needs it will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo arrays or object, try using

```
print_r($offerDetails);
```

or

```
var_dump($offerDetails);
```

Comment: I tried print_r and got this error: Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. I edited OP with the response text.